# Join two RDDs producing empty data

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd, databricks

I have two RDD tables, part and parts.

They have a common column, 'joinKey'. I've tried to join these two tables using this code:

```
part = sc.textFile("/data/tpch/data-001/part/")
parts = sc.textFile("/data/tpch/data-001/parts/")
joinedRDD = part.join(parts)
```

However, when I try to display the joinedRDD
    joinedRDD.take(3)

I get back:

```
[(u'1', (u'|', u'|')), (u'1', (u'|', u'|')), (u'1', (u'|', u'|'))]
```

What gives?

Comment: would you be able to post some data in part and parts could be an issue with how spark is parsing the file. Are they pipe delimited files?

Answer (score 0):

sc.textFile() returns an RDD[String].  You need to parse the string into an array using a split.  Then you need to convert that into a key value rdd, and then join the two.

```
rdd = sc.textFile("path")
rddSplit = rdd.map(lambda l: l.split(delimiter))
rddKey = rddSplit.map(lambda l: l[keyIndex], l)
rddJoin = rddKey.join(rddKey)
```